# virtualenv no such file or directory

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I am using python2.7 on Mac OS 10.8 in the version installed by homebrew. As I had some issues with vtk, I unlinked python (brew unlink python) and linked it again (brew link python). It seems that now the another python version is used, not the homebrew python as I would like. There is no symlink called /usr/local/bin/python anymore, which used to be set before.

Attached the output of `brew --config`, any help is appreciated:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.4
ORIGIN: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew
HEAD: 81f9664508bd290cf73d3b46c2eee647a70b66dd
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: quad-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.8.4-x86_64
Xcode: 4.6.2
CLT: 4.6.0.0.1.1365549073
LLVM-GCC: build 2336
Clang: 4.2 build 425
X11: 2.7.4 => /opt/X11
System Ruby: 1.8.7-358
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/bin/python
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `vtk` issues (especially the python bindings) have beed fixed [today](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/commit/5d0ae0bcbec05b2807a3c561246269497fbbd819) in homebrew-science. But you'll have to `brew update`, `brew rm vtk` and `brew install vtk --with-qt` (I guess you really want the Qt, so VTK supports PyQt).

If you have set your `PATH` so that `/usr/local/bin` comes first, it should pick up a brewed python at `/usr/local/bin/python`. If that symlink is not there, even after `brew link python`, then I can only suggest to `brew reinstall python` to fix that.

If this does not fix your issue, please open an issue at Homebrew's github tracker.

Comment: That's great news, thanks for your comment and moreover for fixing the vtk bug. A reinstallation of python helped, I now can `brew unlink python && brew link python` without problems.